# Is it possible to create a mock "based" on a real class and then stub just some of its methods with Rspec?

Tags: rspec, mocking

When I use

```
user = mock(:user, :something => 'success')
```

I expect `user.something` to return `'success'`, and it's enough in a lot of cases. Mostly, I only need a "thing" named user than returns and specific value when I send it an specific message.

But sometimes, this isn't enough. Sometimes I would like to have an actual `User`, like in `user = User.new` and then "mock" the object so `user.something` returns whatever I need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing this:

```
user = User.new
user.should_receive(:something).and_return(:success)
```

This should do the trick